# How to delete graphics

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

The code below does not execute as I had intended it to do. Clearly, I do not understand where to go from here.

The first click of the mouse sets the initial conditions (t0,x0) for the unique solution to the differential equation and plots the corresponding solution. This action also creates a "Point" at (t0,x0).  Additional clicks produce additional solutions, all of which can be deleted by the "Clear" button. Notice that the most recent "Point" is not overwritten by g = { }.

I cannot figure out how to continue to display the "Points" that represent previous values of {t0,x0} as I click to create new solutions. Also how can I overwrite all previous initial value points with {  } (along with the plots of the corresponding solutions) upon hitting "Clear." Why doesn't AppendTo  keep track of the "Point" that corresponds to the most recent (T0,x0)?

```
xp[t_, r_, t0_, x0_] := 
  x[t] /. First[
    NDSolve[{x'[t] + r x[t] == 0, x[t0] == x0}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]];

Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Plot[g, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 1, Frame -> True, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{t0, x0}]}],

  (AppendTo[g, xp[t, r, #[[1]], #[[2]]]]; {t0, x0} = #) &],

 {{r, 1, "r"}, -10, 10, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 Button["clear", {g = {}}, ImageSize -> {40, 20}],

 Initialization :> {g = {}}]
```

Comment: You already asked 13 questions, so you're an "old" user.Could you tell me why do you vote so sparsely? Are the answers you're receiving (and others that you may hoover over) in this site not worth an upvote?

Comment: I thought that I voted for your solution. In fact, I thought that I voted for most if not all of the answers to my 13 questions. It is true that I have not voted for the hundreds of answers I have "hovered" over. I shall do that from now on if I find the question and/or answer helpful if that is the proper thing for me to do. I certainly wNt to be a good MM

Comment: MMA SE citizen (sorry, I sent off my comment too hastily)

Comment: Good! (BTW, you can see your voting activity in your profile. You voted only 6 times so far :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xp[t_, r_, t0_, x0_] := 
  x[t] /. First[ NDSolve[{x'[t] + r x[t] == 0, x[t0] == x0}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]];

Manipulate[
 ClickPane[
  Plot[g, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 1, Frame -> True, 
       Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}], 
  (AppendTo[g, xp[t, r, #[[1]], #[[2]]]]; {t0, x0} = #; AppendTo[sp, #]) &], 
  {{r, 1, "r"}, -10, 10, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["clear", {g = {}; sp = {}}, ImageSize -> {40, 20}], 
 Initialization :> (g = {}; sp = {}; {x0, t0} = {-1, -1})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: AnoAppendTo for the initial conditions must be added

Comment: you added another AppendTo and initialize toon for the initial conditions. Of course, I should have realized that

Comment: @Stephen Try with locators instead of ClickPane. They are more fun, in particular with LocatorAutoCreate