# Display coordinates of pointing device in VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, manipulate, dynamic

I want to show the coordinates of the (mouse) pointing device as I move the pointing device over the VectorPlot without a (right or left) click. I have tried ToolTip and MousePosition but I cannot get either to work for me. The code below is pared down version based on [a suggestion from Belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66713/193):

```
Manipulate[

sol[t_, t0_, x0_] := 
 x[t] /. First[
   NDSolve[{x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[t0] == x0}, x[t], {t, -2, 2}]];

 ClickPane[
  Show[  Plot[g, {t, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 1, Frame -> True], sf, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}],

 (AppendTo[g, sol[t, #[[1]], #[[2]]]]; {t0, x0} = #; 
 AppendTo[sp, #]) &],

 Initialization :> {(g = {}; sp = {}; {x0, t0} = {-1, -1}),

 sf := VectorPlot[{1, -x}, {t, -2, 2}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 VectorPoints -> 17, VectorScale -> {0.03, Automatic, None}, 
 VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]}
 ]
```

I realize that I need to use Dynamic but the ClickPane seems to mess me up. I need to maintain the functionality of saving the "clicked solutions."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear[xp]
xp[t_, r_, t0_, x0_] := x[t] /.
   First[NDSolve[{x'[t] + r x[t] == 0, x[t0] == x0}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]];

Manipulate[
    ClickPane[ Plot[g, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 1, Frame -> True, 
                   PlotLabel -> Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]],
                   Epilog    -> {PointSize[Large], Point[sp]}],
             (AppendTo[g, xp[t, r, #]]; AppendTo[sp, #]) &],

 {{r, 1, "r"}, -10, 10, 0.01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Button["clear", {g = {}; sp = {}}, ImageSize -> {40, 20}],
 Initialization :> (g = {}; sp = {})]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the definition of `xp` from the link, to make your answer self-contained. Very neat! I had missed it before (+1).

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks! I ran the code from the other answer, and you know ... lingering definitions :)

Comment: @MarcoB Nice! I will add your PlotLabel to the original code .